How to create a custom deserialiser for Apache Flink
I am building a Flink Project using Python that streams events from a Kafka topic. The payload in the topics has been encoded and the SimpleStringSchema is unable to decode them. I have create a custom Deserializer that can decode the messages and added it to the KafkaSource but I get the following error when I run the code:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.fromSource.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.getProducedType(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:56)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.getProducedType(KafkaSource.java:216)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getTypeInfo(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2643)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2015)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayC

Custom Deserializer:
class CustomDeserializationSchema(DeserializationSchema):
    def __init__(self, schema_name):
        super(CustomDeserializationSchema, self).__init__()
        self.schema_name = schema_name

    def deserialize(self, message):
        decoded_message = decode(message)
        return decoded_message

    def isEndOfStream(self, next_element):
        return False

    def getProducedType(self):
        print("Getting produced type")
        return Types.STRING()

Building the source:
source = KafkaSource.builder() \
    .set_bootstrap_servers("server-name") \
    .set_topics("topic-name") \
    .set_group_id("consumer-name")\
    .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
    .set_value_only_deserializer(CustomDeserializationSchema(custom_schema)) \
    .build()

keyed_stream = (
    env
        .from_source(source=source, watermark_strategy=WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), source_name='Ticker source')
        .map(PMapFunction(), Types.STRING())
        .sink_to(sink)
)

